# Touches which object

Tags: iphone, touchesbegan

This may seems simple for you but I would like to know which object is being touched on a view...

I explain...in the viewDidLoad method, I have several objects which are created programmatically (uiimageviews, labels, buttons, etc).

Now in the touchesEnded method, I would like to know which object has been single tapped...how to?

I tried [touch self] == UIImageView], but it's not working...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` callback provides the information you need the `touches` parameter. To extract the view that got the touch use:

```
UIView *touchedView = [[touches anyObject] view];
```

You can then compare:

```
if (myView == touchedView) {
   // do stuff
}
```

More info at [developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: I use the same imageview in the viewDidLoad to display the images then I release it. So i no more have access to the imageviews in the touchesEnded...